# Parsing HTML with Python 2.7 - HTMLParser, SGMLParser, or Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to do some screen-scraping with Python 2.7, and I have no context for the differences between `HTMLParser`, `SGMLParser`, or Beautiful Soup.

Are these all trying to solve the same problem, or do they exist for different reasons? Which is simplest, which is most robust, and which (if any) is the default choice?

Also, please let me know if I have overlooked a significant option.

**Edit:** I should mention that I'm not particularly experienced in HTML parsing, and I'm particularly interested in which will get me moving the quickest, with the goal of parsing HTML on one particular site.

Comment: Getting a hang of xpath usage with lxml with a few good examples would be a good approach IMO. Try these:  http://lxml.de/tutorial.html  & http://www.techchorus.net/web-scraping-lxml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am using and would recommend **lxml** and **pyquery** for parsing HTML. I had to write a web scraping bot a few month ago and of all the popular alternatives I tried, including **HTMLParser** and **BeautifulSoup**, I went with **lxml** and the syntax sugar of **pyquery**. I haven't tried **SGMLParser** though.

For what I've seen, **lxml** is more or less the most feature-rich library and its underlying C core is quite performant when compared to its alternatives. As for **pyquery**, I really liked its jQuery-inspired syntax which makes navigating the DOM more enjoyable.

Here are some resources you might find useful in case you decide to give it a try:

- [lxml home page](http://lxml.de/)
- [pyquery home page](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/)
- [BeautifulSoup vs lxml benchmark](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2010/08/16/beautifulsoup-vs-lxml-performance/)
- [Win installer for pyquery built against Python 2.7](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) - I had a hard time setting up pyquery :)

Well, that's my 2c :) I hope this helps.

Comment: How would you compare `lxml` and `HTMLParser` in terms of ease-of-use, without concern for performance?

Comment: Well, I guess this would depend on your experience and taste, but I personally find lxml's document-oriented approach more intuitive than HTMLParser's stream-based model. So, I find lxml easier to use, but I may not be entirely fair because after my initial comparison of the different libraries a few months ago, I've used lxml only.

Answer (score 6):

BeautifulSoup in particular is for dirty HTML as found in the wild.  It will parse any old thing, but is slow.

A very popular choice these days is lxml.html, which is fast, and can use BeautifulSoup if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/intro/tutorial.html). It is a python framework specifically for scrapping. It makes it very easy to extract information using the [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) to the element. It also has some very interesting capabilities such as defining models for the scraped data (to be able to export it in different formats), authentication and recursively following links.