# Python: Extracting specific data with html parser

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-parsing, html-parser

I started using the HTMLParser in Python to extract data from a website.
I get everything I wanted, except the text within two tags of HTML.
Here is an example of the HTML tag:

```
<a href="http://wold.livingsources.org/vocabulary/1" title="Swahili" class="Vocabulary">Swahili</a>
```

There are also other tags starting with . They have other attributes and values and therefore I do not want to have their data:

```
<a href="http://wold.livingsources.org/contributor#schadebergthilo" title="Thilo Schadeberg" class="Contributor">Thilo Schadeberg</a>
```

The tag is an embedded tag within a table. I don't know if this makes any difference between other tags.
I only want the information in some of the tags called 'a' with the attribute class="Vocabulary" and I want the data within the tag, in the example it would be "Swahili".
So what I did is:

```
class AllLanguages(HTMLParser):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    #counter for the languages
    #countLanguages = 0
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.inLink = False
        self.dataArray = []
        self.countLanguages = 0
        self.lasttag = None
        self.lastname = None
        self.lastvalue = None
        #self.text = ""


    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attr):
        #print "Encountered a start tag:", tag      
        if tag == 'a':
            for name, value in attr:
                if name == 'class' and value == 'Vocabulary':
                    self.countLanguages += 1
                    self.inLink = True
                    self.lasttag = tag
                    #self.lastname = name
                    #self.lastvalue = value
                    print self.lasttag
                    #print self.lastname
                    #print self.lastvalue
                    #return tag
                    print self.countLanguages




    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "a":
            self.inlink = False
            #print "".join(self.data)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.lasttag == 'a' and self.inLink and data.strip():
            #self.dataArray.append(data)
            #
            print data
```

The programm prints every data which is included in an   tag, but I only want the one included in the tag with the right attributes.
How do I get this specific data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set `self.inLink = False` in `handle_starttag` by default:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


class AllLanguages(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.inLink = False
        self.dataArray = []
        self.countLanguages = 0
        self.lasttag = None
        self.lastname = None
        self.lastvalue = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.inLink = False
        if tag == 'a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'class' and value == 'Vocabulary':
                    self.countLanguages += 1
                    self.inLink = True
                    self.lasttag = tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "a":
            self.inlink = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.lasttag == 'a' and self.inLink and data.strip():
            print data


parser = AllLanguages()
parser.feed("""
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<a href="http://wold.livingsources.org/vocabulary/1" title="Swahili" class="Vocabulary">Swahili</a>
<a href="http://wold.livingsources.org/contributor#schadebergthilo" title="Thilo Schadeberg" class="Contributor">Thilo Schadeberg</a>
<a href="http://wold.livingsources.org/vocabulary/2" title="English" class="Vocabulary">English</a>
<a href="http://wold.livingsources.org/vocabulary/2" title="Russian" class="Vocabulary">Russian</a>
</body>
</html>""")
```

prints:

```
Swahili
English
Russian
```

Also, take a look at:

- [scrapy](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/)
- [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I expected it to be sth small ;). 
I try beautifulsoup too and this also works perfect.
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation of using a special parser?
I need the data of the html-file and want to write it in an xml-file. Which one would you use? Or what are the advantages of one of the parser?

Comment: Well, beautifulspoup and lxml are decent html parsers. lxml is famous for it's speed, beautifulsoup is pretty handy but doesn't support xpath expressions. See more: http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494199/parsing-html-with-python-2-7-htmlparser-sgmlparser-or-beautiful-soup.

Comment: Well, I have to parse a lot of data, therefore beautifulsoup is pretty slow. But I think I will try lxml. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You may try HTQL (http://htql.net).  The query for:

"the tags called 'a' with the attribute class="Vocabulary" and I want the data within the tag"

is:

```
<a (class='Vocabulary')>:tx
```

The python code is something like this:

```
import htql
a=htql.query(page, "<a (class='Vocabulary')>:tx")
print(a)
```