# Scrape alexa and show results in table in django

Tags: python, html, django, alexa-internet

I want to create a simple (one page) web application using Django, and see the top 20 websites from alexa.com/topsites/global. The page should render a table with 21 rows (1 header and 20 websites) and 3 columns (rank, website and description).

My knowledge using django is limitted and I really need some help if possible.

I've used a template to create a table using some bootstrap but I actually don't have any idea on how to parse: rank / website name / and description.

Could anybody lead me in the right direction with some usefull websites / code snippets ?

I know that I have to use `HTMLParser` and implement something like:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered some data  :", data

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

But I don't know how to use it on my requirements in my application.

---

So, I am comming back with an update. I've tried to do this (just to print the results to see if I get what I want) but I only get some links.

Any help ?

```
import urllib2, HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def reset(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.reset(self)
        #count div to get the rank of website
        self.in_count_div = False
        #description div to get description of website
        self.in_description_div = False
        #a tag to get the url
        self.in_link_a = False

        self.count_items = None
        self.a_link_items = None
        self.description_items = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'div':
            if('class', 'count') in attrs:
                self.in_count_div = True

        if tag == 'a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'href':
                    self.a_link_items = [value,'']
                    self.in_link_a = True
                    break

        if tag == 'div':
            if('class', 'description') in attrs:
                self.in_description_div = True

    #handle data for each section
    def handle_data_count(self, data):
        if self.in_count_div:
            self.count_items[1] += data

    def handle_data_url(self, data):
        if self.in_link_a:
            self.a_link_items[1] += data

    def handle_data_description(self, data):
        if self.in_description_div:
            self.description_items[1] += data

    #endtag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag =='div':
            if self.count_items is not None:
                print self.count_items
            self.count_items = None
            self.in_count_div = False

        if tag =='a':
            if self.a_link_items is not None:
                print self.a_link_items
            self.a_link_items = None
            self.in_link_a = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myhtml = MyHTMLParser()
    myhtml.feed(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.alexa.com/topsites/global').read())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an API there is one for Alexa [here](http://aws.amazon.com/alexa-top-sites/)

If you want too scrape, i'd suggest **BeautifulSoup** 
(scrapy is to heavy for this since the only thing you'll be doing is reading from one URL.)

Doing this is simple:

- Make a python module that deals with pulling data from the Alexa link using BeautifulSoup, in the module make it so that it runs the task every 5 minutes or any time span your application will be efficient with, then save it to your database.
- To display the data you would retrieve it from the database then pass it to the template in a template variable, and the html should look something like this (don't use tables):

> ```
> <table>
>     {% for site in top_20_sites %}
>     <tr>
>         <td>{{site.rank}}</td>
>         <td>{{site.name}}</td>
>         <td>{{site.description}}</td>
>     <\tr>
>     {% endfor %}
> </table>
> ```

As for how to scrape see this awesome tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk)

Comment: Since you are new to django i suggest you go throught this tutorial:
http://tangowithdjango.com/book17/

Comment: It is necessary to add that info into a database ? Or can I retrieve it every 5 minutes from the website ? Let's say I'll have a list for `site.rank` , one for `site.name` and one for `site.descrpition`. I will go through each item with a `for` loop and put the info into a table. Is this possible ?

Comment: I have tried something. Could you lead me in the right direction ? Thanks :) I don't want to use beautifulsoup.

Comment: You can make it such that the scraping runs every time a user hits your page, but that will be unnecessary in most cases, and also resource consuming.  
You can set it to less than 5 minutes thou, it depends on the application requirements.  
i took a look at Alexa's page, you should look for an ``<li>`` element with ``class="site-listing"`` , nested inside that <li> you will find the description div with ``class="description"`` and a div with class="desc-paragraph" containing an anchor tag <a> with the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a quick Google search you'll find a bunch of SO questions on how to use the HTMLParser module. Off the top of the results, these 2 questions seem pertinent to what you're trying to do (extract specific tags):

- [How can I use the python HTMLParser library to extract data from a specific div tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276040/how-can-i-use-the-python-htmlparser-library-to-extract-data-from-a-specific-div)
- [Python: Extracting specific data with html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773583/python-extracting-specific-data-with-html-parser)

But -- as the other answer above suggests -- you'll save a lot of work using a library like BeautifulSoup to parse and extract tags:

- [Beautiful Soup Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Once you have the extracted data -- using whatever method you choose -- the Django presentation part should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build a crawler with Scrapy, set it up running every day, save the data on your database and make a site with Django that shows the latest results. All in Python.

Comment: Because I want to learn the way I asked for. I am not looking for a solution but a specific one.